# I want to do appear an Insterstitial ad WHEN flash is OFF

Tags: android, admob, ads

i have this code, and i want to do appear an insterstitial ad when the flash is off (my app is a flashlight) But when i try to do it i get an error.

All what i do is to put the onReceiveAd code where i want it.

I put the code here:

```
    // Switch button click event to toggle flash on/off
    btnSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isFlashOn) {
                // turn off flash
                turnOffFlash();  <---- FLASH GO OFF
            @Override
public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad) {    <------ Insterstitial AD should APPEAR
  Log.d("OK", "Received ad");
  if (ad == interstitial) {
    interstitial.show();
  }
}
```

} else{ 
etc etc...

But i get this error:
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token "(", ; 
     expected
    - Syntax error on token ")", ; 
     expected

How can i do to do it works?

```
private InterstitialAd interstitial;

      @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            // Create the interstitial
            interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this, "My id here");

            // Create ad request
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();

            // Begin loading your interstitial
            interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

            // Set Ad Listener to use the callbacks below
            interstitial.setAdListener(this);






    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Touch amumu's body to play a sound!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // flash switch button
    btnSwitch = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


    // First check if device is supporting flashlight or not        
    hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
            .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

    if (!hasFlash) {
        // device doesn't support flash
        // Show alert message and close the application
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .create();
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setMessage("Sorry, your device doesn't support flash light!");
        alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // closing the application
                finish();
            }
        });
        alert.show();
        return;
    } 


    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);


    ImageView Facebook = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    Facebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.draven);

                                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        mp.release();
                                    }
                                }); 

                                mp.start();

                                Intent facebookIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                facebookIntent.setType("text/plain");
                                facebookIntent.setPackage("com.facebook.katana");
                                facebookIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lol.flashlight");
                                startActivity(facebookIntent);

                            }});



    ImageView Twitter = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    Twitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.draven);

            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mp.release();
                }
            }); 

            mp.start();
            //al apretar click en el boton Ir a Web abre el browser con la pág: google.com
            Intent browserIntent = 
                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                    Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lol.flashlight%20-%20This%20app%20is%20amazing,%20i%20love%20it!"));
           startActivity(browserIntent);




            }});

    //OnClick del View :D
    ImageView Ez = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    Ez.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.amumu);

    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.release();
        }
    }); 

    mp.start();
    }});  





    // get the camera
    getCamera();

    // displaying button image
    toggleButtonImage();


    // Switch button click event to toggle flash on/off
    btnSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isFlashOn) {
                // turn off flash
                turnOffFlash();
            } else {
                // turn on flash
                turnOnFlash();
            }
        }
    });
}


// Get the camera
private void getCamera() {
    if (camera == null) {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
            params = camera.getParameters();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e("Camera Error. Failed to Open. Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}


 // Turning On flash
private void turnOnFlash() {
    if (!isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }
        // play sound
        playSound();

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();
        isFlashOn = true;

        // changing button/switch image
        toggleButtonImage();
    }

}


// Turning Off flash
private void turnOffFlash() {
    if (isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }
        // play sound
        playSound();

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.stopPreview();
        isFlashOn = false;

        // changing button/switch image
        toggleButtonImage();
    }
}


 // Playing sound
 // will play button toggle sound on flash on / off
private void playSound(){
    if(isFlashOn){
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.playbutton);
    }else{
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.rayo);
    }
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.release();
        }
    }); 
    mp.start();
}

/*
 * Toggle switch button images
 * changing image states to on / off
 * */
private void toggleButtonImage(){
    if(isFlashOn){
        btnSwitch.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
    }else{
        btnSwitch.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // on pause turn off the flash
    turnOffFlash();

}


@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // on starting the app get the camera params
    getCamera();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // on stop release the camera
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.release();
        camera = null;


    }

}
@Override
public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad) {
  Log.d("OK", "Received ad");
  if (ad == interstitial) {
    interstitial.show();
  }
}


@Override
public void onDismissScreen(Ad arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad arg0, ErrorCode arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void onLeaveApplication(Ad arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void onPresentScreen(Ad arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }


}
```

Comment: You can't declare a method inside onClick method in that way. You must put just `interstitial.show();`

Comment: Other point is that `ad` and `interstitial` are not the same types, so can't be equal. This binary operator always return false.

Comment: @CaptainTeemo Thanks dude, it works perfectly!
Captain Teemo on duty!